# What is wrong with this claim?

Tags: discussion

I'm skeptical of (The Huffington Post)

> Homosexuality as a deterrent to overpopulation is a hypothesis proposed by scientific researchers applicable not just to homo sapiens, but throughout the animal world.

That is a strong claim, it’s corroborated by the entire article (and elsewhere, it’s a pretty well-known and widely repeated claim) and there’s good reason to be sceptical of it.

What is wrong?

Perhaps the claim is not a notable one, or are there other reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most apparent thing is that nobody is claiming anything about homosexuality:

> Homosexuality … **is a hypothesis proposed by scientific researchers** …

Speculation, when clearly marked as such, is not a claim.

On the other hand you may be skeptical that *such a hypothesis has been proposed at all*. That could be a valid claim, but really, barely notable. I wouldn't consider it as a very interesting claim, but that's clearly my personal view.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the claim to make the question better, +1.